# File folders with data

Tags: windows, files-folders

How can i have a list of folders in file manager identify how many items are in each folder or at least show which folders are empty without having to look at each folder?

Comment: Bit of a leap, but do you simply want to delete empty folders in a directory?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in **Explorer**. To get a list of empty folders in **PowerShell**, you can use:

```
gci -dir -recurse | ? { !(gci -LiteralPath  $_.FullName -force) } | select FullName
```

If you want to delete empty folders:

```
gci -dir -recurse | ? { !(gci -LiteralPath  $_.FullName -force) } | Remove-Item -force
```